# Set-based approach to applying payments to bills

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to show payments applied to bills and I'd like to know if there is a way to do this without using cursors and imperative logic. I have a Bills table and Payments table. Payments are not always in the amounts of the bills, sometimes over, sometimes under. I'm trying to create some sort of join that shows how much of each payment was applied to each bill.

Assumptions:

- Bills belong to a single account
- Payments are applied to each bill in order of its ID

Given a Bills table:

```
ID  Amount
1   500
2   500
3   500
```

Scenario 1:

Payments table

```
ID  Amount
1   750
2   750
```

With the above Bills table, and the scenario 1 payments table, I would like to see this output:

```
Bill ID | Payment ID | Amount Applied
1   1   500
2   2   250
3   2   500
3   2   250
```

Scenario 2:

```
Payments table:
1   300
2   300
3   300
4   300
5   300
```

Given above Bills table and scenario 2 Payments table, I would like to see output:

```
Bill ID | Payment ID | Amount Applied
1   1   300
1   2   200
2   2   100
2   3   300
2   4   100
3   4   200
3   5   300
```

I can do this with cursors, but I'd like to find out if anyone knows how to do this with set-based SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: I could only think of possibly using a recursive CTE, but haven't yet figured out exactly how to apply it

Comment: Is there no table to relate a payment to a bill?

Comment: Are you able to alter your tables? Normally you would have a relation on your payments table to the bills table, many to one. It should only take 2 tables to represent your data -  properly normalized.

Comment: I would not attempt this would having a table that relates payments to bills.  When payments are entered, you determine which bills to apply them to and maintain the table at that point.  IMO this is something to store and not to calculate each time you display it.

Comment: Here is a case where payments are mapped to expenses on a set based approach [SQL Payments for Expenses Query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-tutorial-map-payments-to-expenses-using-t-sql-query.aspx)  I think you can convert the script that can be useful in your case

Comment: In this case, I could not alter tables, and there is no relating table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL 2005 requires a few more steps, because it lacks the `SUM() OVER(ORDER BY...)` and `LAG()` functions, but the basic idea is the same: calculate running totals of the Bills and Payments.

Each bill can be in one of three states: not paid, fully paid, or partially paid. Comparing the running totals will determine the state. The difference between the current and previous state will be the amount of payment applied to that bill in the current cycle.

**SQL 2005**

```
WITH
  Bills_RunningTotal AS (
    SELECT
       b_ID = b1.ID
      ,b_Amount = b1.Amount
      ,b_RunningTotal = SUM(b2.Amount)
    FROM Bills b1
    INNER JOIN Bills b2
      ON (b2.ID <= b1.ID)
    GROUP BY b1.ID,b1.Amount
  )
 ,Payments_RunningTotal AS (
    SELECT
       p_ID = p1.ID
      ,p_Amount = p1.Amount
      ,p_RunningTotal = SUM(p2.Amount)
    FROM Payments p1
    INNER JOIN Payments p2
      ON (p2.ID <= p1.ID)
    GROUP BY p1.ID,p1.Amount
  )
 ,Bills_Payments_RemainderDue AS (
    SELECT
      b_ID
     ,p_ID
     ,b_Previous_Remainder_Due = CASE
       WHEN b_RunningTotal + p_Amount < p_RunningTotal THEN 0
       WHEN b_RunningTotal + p_Amount > p_RunningTotal + b_Amount THEN b_Amount
       ELSE b_RunningTotal + p_Amount - p_RunningTotal
     END 
     ,b_Current_Remainder_Due = CASE
       WHEN b_RunningTotal < p_RunningTotal THEN 0
       WHEN b_RunningTotal > p_RunningTotal + b_Amount THEN b_Amount
       ELSE b_RunningTotal - p_RunningTotal
     END
     FROM Bills_RunningTotal b
     CROSS JOIN Payments_RunningTotal p
  )
SELECT
  [Bill ID] = b_ID
 ,[Payment ID] = p_ID
 ,[Amount Applied] = b_Previous_Remainder_Due - b_Current_Remainder_Due
FROM Bills_Payments_RemainderDue
WHERE b_Previous_Remainder_Due - b_Current_Remainder_Due > 0
ORDER BY [Bill ID],[Payment ID]
```

**SQL 2008+**

Using ordered windowed functions, the query can be made more efficient.

```
WITH
  Bills_Payments_RunningTotal AS (
    SELECT
       b_ID = b.ID
      ,p_ID = p.ID
      ,b_Amount = b.Amount
      ,p_Amount = p.Amount
      ,b_RunningTotal = SUM(b.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY b.ID)
      ,p_RunningTotal = SUM(p.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY b.ID ORDER BY p.ID)
    FROM Bills b
    CROSS JOIN Payments p
  )
 ,Bills_Payments_RemainderDue AS (
    SELECT b_ID,p_ID,b_Amount,p_Amount
     ,b_Current_Remainder_Due = CASE
        WHEN b_RunningTotal < p_RunningTotal THEN 0
        WHEN b_RunningTotal > p_RunningTotal + b_Amount THEN b_Amount
        ELSE b_RunningTotal - p_RunningTotal
      END
    FROM Bills_Payments_RunningTotal
  )
 ,Bills_Payments_AmountApplied AS (
    SELECT 
      [Bill ID] = b_ID
     ,[Payment ID] = p_ID
     ,[Amount Applied] = ISNULL(LAG(b_Current_Remainder_Due) OVER(PARTITION BY b_ID ORDER BY p_ID),b_Amount) - b_Current_Remainder_Due
    FROM Bills_Payments_RemainderDue
  )
SELECT [Bill ID],[Payment ID],[Amount Applied]
FROM Bills_Payments_AmountApplied
WHERE [Amount Applied] > 0
ORDER BY [Bill ID],[Payment ID]
```